Maxwell–Boltzmann distribution derivation using only thermodynamic equations
I want to derive the Maxwell–Boltzmann distribution using only the fundamental relation and the Boltzmann's entropy formula.
$dU=TdS-pdV\tag1$
$S=k_b ln(\Omega)\tag2$
So using only the two equations I get:
$$dS=k_b\frac{1}{\Omega} d\Omega$$
$$dS=\frac{1}{T}dU$$
$$\frac{1}{T}dU=k_b\frac{1}{\Omega} d\Omega$$
$$\frac{1}{Tk_b}dU=\frac{1}{\Omega} d\Omega$$
$$\frac{U}{Tk_b}=ln(\Omega)$$
$U=\frac{mv^2}{2}$ I also substitute the kinetic energy formula.
$$\frac{mv^2}{2Tk_b}=ln(\Omega)$$
$$\Omega=exp\left(\frac{mv^2}{2Tk_b}\right)$$
$$\frac{1}{\Omega}=exp\left(\frac{-mv^2}{2Tk_b}\right)$$
$$P(v)=\frac{exp\left(\frac{-mv^2}{2Tk_b}\right)}{\sum exp\left(\frac{-mv^2}{2Tk_b}\right)}$$
$$P(v)=\frac{exp\left(\frac{-mv^2}{2Tk_b}\right)}{\displaystyle Z}$$
where ${\displaystyle Z=\sum exp\left(\frac{-mv^2}{2Tk_b}\right)}={\displaystyle Z=\sum _{i}e^{-\beta E_{i}}}$ is the canonical partition function (whatever that means).
and so
$${\displaystyle f(\mathbf {v} )~d^{3}\mathbf {v} =A\exp \left(-{\frac {mv^{2}}{2k_{\text{B}}T}}\right)~d^{3}\mathbf {v} }$$
where $A$ is the normalization constant I obtain by solving the Gaussian integral.
I want to derive it like this, because I am not yet familiar so much with statistical mechanics, but I know classical thermodynamics and I wonder if this derivation is "legal" (whatever that means).

Your two assumptions have neither probability nor velocity in them, so why do you expect you can get the MB distribution, which gives probability of velocities?

$U=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ is additional assumption (3), but it is about single molecule, this $U$ does not obey (1). You can't do physics just by manipulating symbols, symbols are used to denote some meaningful quantity, but often you can find the same symbol used with different meanings in different text. So $U$ in (3) is different from $U$ in (1).

Also, it seems you integrated $dU/T$ as if $T$ does not depend on $U$. But it does, e.g. for ideal gas, $T=\frac{U}{\frac{f}{2}Nk_B}$.

Probably not legal, for a few reasons. The thermal energy $U$ tends to depend on $T$, so that side $dU/T$ needs to be integrated properly. Additionally, the probability should be proportional to $\Omega$, not $1/\Omega$.
Thermodynamic quantities typically deal with macroscopic numbers of particles, so the thermal energy $U$ refers to $N$ particles. The equipartition theorem for a monatomic ideal gas, which perhaps you want to avoid, equates $U=3NkT/2$ with $U=\sum_i \frac{m v_i^2}{2}=Nm\bar{v^2}/2$ for root-mean-square velocity $v_{RMS}=\sqrt{\bar{v^2}}$. This makes manifest the requisite temperature dependence and particle-number dependence that make the derivation in question "illegal."

I would add that it equate the average energy of the ensemble $U$ with the energy of a single microstate (and for a single particle) $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$

@BySymmetry another good reason why it's not legal! I'll put in the full equipartition theorem, why not

Your approach is doomed to fail.
The classical ideal gas obeying Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution rather famously has the quantum-defying Sackur-Tetrode entropy. It is unbounded below as $T\to0$, and so then $\Omega$ is undefine-able.
Boltzmann's formula should be paired with quantum theory, i.e. you should derive either Bose-Einstein distribution or Fermi-Dirac distribution, or both, and then take the limits to Maxwell-Boltzmann if you want that.
